# How to pass python list as an function argument using CLR and pythonnet to the imported dotnet function?

Tags: python, c#, .net, clr

I am using pythonnet by importing CLR in python. I have a python list which has some string values . I want to pass this list as an argument to the dotnet function which is imported from C sharp using CLR in python.

I am able to pass individual integer and string values in this function but not any list or container as it gives error " TypeError: No method matches given arguments for Function"

```
import clr

clr.AddReference('MyProject')

from MyProject import MyClass
from System.Collections.Generic import List
instance = MyClass()

instance.Myfunc(pythonlist)
```

I have referenced 'MyProject.dll' here Where Myfunc is a dotnet function which tries to take list of strings as aargument and gives results, but it does not work while it works fine if I take individual element pythonlist[1] and change the dotnet function argument type as string or integer.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide some code what you want to do?

Comment: Hi I have updated with code.

Comment: The arguments are strings so for a list you can use CSV (list objects separated by a comma or other character).

Comment: Thanks jdweng, but there are multiple list elements there and I need to pass the complete list only, I am looking for a way which can correlate the python list and "dotnet list. I also tried the normal python way for imported function as instance.Myfunc(*pythonlist)", then also it is not supporting.